# Return a value from an ajax call to parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, return

I have a function where I need to return a url that I am getting via an ajax call.

```
var heatmap = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        var tileURL;
        $.get('getimage.php', { zoom: zoom, x: coord.x, y: coord.y }, function(data) {
            if(data.status) { tileURL=data.image; }
        }, "json");
        return "tileURL";
    },
       tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
       opacity:0.55,
       isPng: true
});
```

Obviously, the ajax call is asynchronous so I understand why the above code will return tileURL as undefined.  I know in general people use callback functions  to solve this issue, but I don't know how to get a call back to RETURN a value to the parent function.  I'm working with the google maps API, so I don't really have any flexibility to change how that works.

Comment: See [
How do I return a variable from Google Maps JavaScript geocoder callback?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993563/how-do-i-return-a-variable-from-google-maps-javascript-geocoder-callback)

Answer (score 4):

Because the Ajax request is asynchronous, your only option is to use a callback. If you could return a value to the "parent" (really, "calling") function, then the request wouldn't be asynchronous; it would block the calling function. Also, there is no way to get a reference to the calling function from within a closure in that function. (i.e., you can't `return` to a function higher up in the call stack).

Comment: So, are you saying its not possible to do what I want, assuming I can't change the way the getTileUrl function works in the google maps api?  Because a callback wouldn't help me actually return the value to that getTileUrl function.

Comment: Check the link @Matthew Flaschen posted above, it will help you.