# Getting the return from a 'shown' event handler inside a function - JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, nested, return

I have a function called `foo` which is supposed to return the current visible element, but returns `undefined` instead.

```
function foo(){
  $('.bar').on('shown', function(){           // 'shown' is a bootstrap .js event
    return ($(this).attr('id').split('baz')); // returns 'undefined'
  });
}
```

According to Pointy's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8901816/3284936), it does not make sense to return values from event handlers. If that's the case, what would be the conventional way to retrieve the return of `foo();` when needed?

Comment: You could cache out the data you need in a higher scoped var (before foo).

Comment: Show html of `.bar`

Comment: `.bar` is actually `.accordion-toggle` (Bootstrap accordion class). If I CL it as `$('.accordion-toggle').length`, I get 3, which matches the number of accordions I have on page.

Comment: @JamesCollier to a global var?

Comment: @Dimitry_N not global because that's frowned upon. Say foo() is in a class, make a var at the class level.

Comment: @JamesCollier ahh, the ES6 sorcery. Will give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method... It makes no sense how foo would use an event to return what was shown. Your event handler should execute the code that needs than...

Comment: @Dimitry_N consider a function inside of an object, or a function. That would work, too.