# JS global variable not being set on first iteration

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to give a global variable a value after some code is processed. It's not working as planned.

What I do is enter an address and city in two textboxes. It goes into the last function and calls codeAddress which gets the coordinates of the address.

From there i send the coordinates to setLatLng and it works fine. But i can't call longlats using the getLatLng to see the set value.

It'll only show a value if I add an address and city two times. I'm thinking the longlats are being initialized too late that I don't see the correct value in time.

Any advice?

Relevant code is below.

```
<script>
var longlats ="";

function setLatLng(x,y){
    longlats = x+","+y;
    alert(longlats) //shows value
}

function getLatLng(){
    alert(longlats);
    return longlats;
    //calling this gives undefined
}

function codeAddress() {

$('#map').show();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById("address").value +"," + document.getElementById("city").value;

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    locationsall[counter] = new Array();
    locationsall[counter][0] = address;
    locationsall[counter][1] = lat; //has value
    locationsall[counter][2] = lng; //has value
    setLatLng(locationsall[counter][1],locationsall[counter][2]);

counter++;

} 

$(function() {
$("#locationadd").click(function() {
   codeAddress();
   var get = getLatLng();//value is undefined..
  //i want to do stuff with the values in longlats
}
)};

</script>
```

Edit1

```
 $("#locationadd").click(function() {
var address = $("#address").val();
var city = $("#city").val();

if (address =="" || city =="") {
    $("#locationtext").text('*Please enter an address and city');
    return false;
} 
else {
    codeAddress(function(){
    var get = getLatLng();
    var longlat = get.split(",");
    var lat = longlat[0];
    var lng = longlat[1];

    var $tr2 = $('<tr>').css({
            'padding': '4px',
            'background-color': '#ddd'
    }).appendTo('#locationDeals');

    var location = [
            address,
            city
    ];
    locations.push(location);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var $td2 = $('<td>').appendTo($tr2);
        $('<span>').text(location[i]).appendTo($td2);
        $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
            'name': 'loc[' + ctr + '][' + i + ']',
            'value': location[i]
        }).appendTo($td2);
    }
    var $tdRemoveRow2 = $('<td>').appendTo($tr2);
    $('<a>').attr({
        'href': '#',
        'id': 'submit-button'
    }).text("Remove").click(function() {
    var index2 = $tr2.index();
    $("#locationDeals input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
        this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(str2, number2) {
          return "[" + (+number2 > index2 - 1 ? number2 - 1 : number2) + "]";
        });
    });

    $tr2.remove();
    var tmp = locations.splice(locations.indexOf(location), 1);
    deleteMarker(tmp);
    return false;
    }).appendTo($tdRemoveRow2);

    ctr++;
    document.getElementById("address").value = "";
    document.getElementById("city").value = "";
    document.getElementById("address").focus();
    $("#locationtext").text('');

    return false;
    });
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `geocoder.geocode` is asynchronous. You can't do it the way you do because your `codeAddress` function will return before `longlats` is set. You need to change your coding style to use longlats only after google maps have returned the result.

You need to change your code from this:

```
$("#locationadd").click(function() {
   codeAddress();
   var get = getLatLng();//value is undefined..
  //i want to do stuff with the values in longlats
}
```

To this:

```
$("#locationadd").click(function() {
   codeAddress(function(){
     var get = getLatLng();
     //do stuff with the values in longlats
   });
});
```

In order to do that, you need to change `copyAddress` to:

```
function codeAddress(callback) {

  /*
   * Some stuff
   */

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      /*
       * Some stuff
       */

      setLatLng(locationsall[counter][1],locationsall[counter][2]);

      callback(); // This is where/when the values are returned
                  // so this is where/when we want to execute code.  
    } 
  })
}
```

---

### Additional explanation:

From your comments, it appears that you're still trying to do this:

```
var val;
codeAddress(function(){
    val = getLatLng();
});
doStuffWith(val);
```

This won't work because codeAddress returns BEFORE getLatLng executes. You need to **change the style of your coding**. You need to write it like this:

```
codeAddress(function(){
    val = getLatLng();
    doStuffWith(val);
});
```

That is, you need to **move all code that you would have written after the call to codeAddress to the function INSIDE codeAddress**.

The reason for it is that the way the code executes is something like this:

- BROWSER ENTERS JAVASCRIPT PHASE:

  ```
     codeAddress is called
            |
            |
            |--------------> inside codeAddress a request to google maps
            |                is made which registers a callback function
            |                to be executed once it returns.
            v
     codeAddress returns
     note that at this point getLatLng isn't called yet
     this is because the browser haven't made the request
     to google maps yet because it's still executing the
     javascript engine.
            |
            v
     code written after codeAddress is executed
     (remember, the call to google maps still haven't happened yet)
            |
            v
     no more javascript to execute
  ```
- javascript phase ends, BROWSER ENTERS DOM RENDERING PHASE

  ```
     The DOM gets updated and drawn on screen if there are any changes.
  ```
- DOM rendering ends, BROWSER ENTERS NETWORK PHASE

  ```
     (note: in reality the network layer is asynchronous)

     Browser executes pending requests (images, iframes, XMLHttprequest etc.)
     Makes the necessary network connections and begins downloading stuff.
            |
            |
            v
     Browser services completed requests and schedules appropriate events
     (update DOM, trigger onreadystatechange etc.)
     Note that at this point no javascript or DOM updates actually happens.
     The browser does things in a loop, not recursively.
     It is at this point that the google maps request is made.
            |
            v
     No more network operations to service
  ```
- network phase ends, BROWSER ENTERS JAVASCRIPT PHASE

  ```
     google maps request completes, onreadystatechange executes
            |
            |
            |----> inside onreadystatechange the callback to the
            |      google maps API is called
            |             |
            |             '-----> inside the google maps callback getLatLng
            |                     is called, then the callback to codeAddress
            |                     is called.
            |                          |
            |                          '------> inside the callback to
            |                                   codeAddress you can now
            |                                   use the returned values.
            |                                   This is the reason you need
            |                                   to move all your code here.
            v
     no more javascript to execute
  ```
- javascript phase ends, BROWSER ENTERS DOM RENDERING PHASE

and the event loop continues.

As you can see, you can't simply return the values from codeAddress. Instead you need to move your code inside codeAddress to have it executed at the right time.

Comment: Is there any reason that doing this could cause my form to be submitted? I'v edited the code to include the stuff i do in the codeAddress callback.

Comment: Is `#locationadd` a submit button?

Comment: No, <button id="locationadd">Add</button></td> the submit button is below it. I wrapped that entire code in the codeaddress(function(){ code. is that maybe causing it? http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/inputform.php <- live code

Comment: Seems like it just being in there makes the form want to post. Not sure why

Comment: `<button>`s have default behavior similar to `<input type=submit>`. You need to prevent this. Either return false from the onclick function or call the various browser-specific preventDefault functions

Comment: Using  codeAddress(function(){var val = getLatLng()}) how do i get the val code right after? right after that line i want to alert(val); and it doens't work?

Comment: You don't. As explained, the function inside codeAdress does not execute immediately. Instead it only executes after google have returned with the result. codeAddress meanwhile returns. Which means that anything you write after codeAddress will execute BEFORE getLatLng. That is why you need to put code INSIDE codeAddress, NOT AFTER.

Answer (score 0):

You get `undefined` because when calling `getLatLng()` the value of `longlats` hasn't been set yet.

Your function `codeAddress()` makes an async request, so you need to make it able to accept a callback as an argument.

```
codeAddress(function(longLat){
    // do something with longLat
});
```

When declaring the function codeAddress make sure to execute the callback and pass it the longLat value.

[check this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993563/how-do-i-return-a-variable-from-google-maps-javascript-geocoder-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Google geocoding service makes an AJAX call which is asynchronous. When you call `codeAddess()` it fires the AJAX request and immediately returns. The response has not been received yet so your variable has not been set but you try to get it with `getLatLng()` anyway which shows up an empty alert box (I suppose). What you want to do is pass a callback to the geocoding function and do your subsequent work there. For example,

```
function codeAddress(fn) {
   /* Code here */
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
     /* More code here */
     /* Call callback in the end or after setting*/
     fn();
  }
}
```

You can set it up like this:

```
$("#locationadd").click(function() {
   codeAddress(getLatLng);
});
```

Comment: How come doing var val = codeAddress(getLatLng) doesn't work? It seems to try to post my form instead of doing the right thing. I want to be able to use the returned value.

Comment: Posting the form is a different issue. As for assigning to `val`, it's asynchronous as I mentioned. You need to do: `codeAddress(function(){var val = getLatLng()})`