# cant get the latitudes and longitude values from google maps in to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to get the values of longitude and latitude in to an array..

```
 function codeAddress(address) {
    var place;
    var lines=[];

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      place=results[0].geometry.location;
str=place.lng();
        lines.push(place.lng());
        lines.push(place.lat());

         });
    console.log(lines);
    console.log(lines.length);

    return lines;
  }
```

but lines.length is shown as zero.. when i try to print the array lines, when i check it using firebug, it shows empty array `[]`  bt when i try click on the [], it shows opens and shows

```
[]
0    1.32323
1    125.12323
```

i'm not sure what is wrong..

when i try to `console.log(results[0].geometry.location)` 
it shows `R { ib=1.32323, jb=125.12323, toString=function(), more...}`

Comment: Geocoding is asynchronous.  You have to use the data in the callback function (when it is available), you can't return it from the function.

Comment: so can research the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993563/how-do-i-return-a-variable-from-google-maps-javascript-geocoder-callback