# How to remove square brackets in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array called `value` and when I `console.log(value)` I get about 30 lines of code with the following `[6.443663, 3.419248]`

The numbers change as they are Latitudes and Longitudes. But I need to somehow get rid of the square brackets around each one.

I tried `var replaced = value.toString().replace(/\[.*\]/g,'');` but this changed the above example to `6.443407,3.419035000000008` and failed my code.

In other words I need help getting rid of square brackets in an array in order to plot points on my map.

My array is made up from the following code because each latitude and longitude value is held within `onClick` functions within `a` links. So a member on here kindly supplied the below code to get my values into an array but now I'm struggling to get the values out without any brackets ruining it.

```
var obj = {};
$('.choice-location-inner a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.attr('onClick').replace('findLocation(\'', '').replace('\');return false;', '');
    var array = text.split(',')
    obj[this.id]= [parseFloat(array[0]), parseFloat(array[1])];
});
```

The array is trying to plot markers on my Google Map using the following code

```
$.each(obj , function(index, value){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': value}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            wait = true;
            setTimeout("wait = false", 1000);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What *exactly* is `value`?  An array, a string?  `console.log(typeof value)` please.

Comment: Do you mean the lat/lng values are stored as a string in the array, such as array[0] = "[23.021321,18.213123]"?

Comment: If `value` is array, then `value.toString()` is the same as `value.join(',')`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat `console.log(typeof value)` returns as `Object`

Comment: @DonaldSutherland: So, what *exactly* are you trying to do with the array?  Display it?  `console.log` it?  What?  (remember, your array is multi-dimentional)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I have updated the code to show you how I'm trying to get the array to work. I'm trying to plot each array item onto my Google Map

Comment: Can you show the exact output from firebug for console.log(value)

Comment: @DonaldSutherland: Ok, so what's the issue?  Does that not work?  Have you tried just doing `{ 'address': value.join(',') }`?

Comment: @DonaldSutherland: Since you are sending coordinates and not an address, have you tried using `new google.maps.LatLng` and `geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2993614)?

Comment: When you `console.log` an array, the `[]` are shown to tell you it's an array.  It's *not* logging a string.  If you want a string, you need to convert it to one.  `value.toString() is the same as value.join(',')`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat When I used `value.toString()` the following `[6.443663, 3.419248]` gets changed to `6.443407,3.419035000000008`

Comment: @DonaldSutherland: Yes, yes it does.  That's because `value.toString()` is the same as `value.join(',')`, which return strings.  When `console.log` is called on a string, they are displayed as-is, when it's called on an array, `[]` is *added* to show that it's an array.  (Also, you're getting `3.419035000000008` because floating-point numbers are weird.)  Again, what is not working about this code?

Comment: @DonaldSutherland: Yea, that's fine.  It's a string now.  Does `{ 'address': value.toString() }` not work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I've misread and the item is an object rather than a string with brackets contained, the you could just access it by its sub array poition

```
lat = obj[this.id][0]
lng = obj[this.id][1]
```

perhaps?

Comment: is there a way to do this without using the index if the array is only one element long?

Answer (score 13):

transforms the line to array to text.

```
var value = [[1234213, 1234231], [1234213, 1234231]];
var dato = value[0];
console.log(dato.toString());
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you want the comma separated string representation of the array. If that's the case, you can do this:

```
var commasep = value.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`${arr.map(({ id }) => id)}`
```

Maybe this way a lot simple other than using inbuilt functions!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a clean input you can write this.

```
var justTheDataWithoutSeparation = data.split('');
```

of course, if you want to separate with commas or something else, you need to add

```
vat dataSeparatedWithSomething = data.split('-');
```

> You need to be careful because doing this method can cause your data to set like string value, and may affect your output, you need to convert that before.