# Return value with google maps geocoder

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just can't find what's wrong with this bit of code:

```
function getLocationName(latitude, longitude) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(latitude)) || isNaN(parseFloat(longitude))) {
        return false;
    }

    var locationName;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)

    // Reverse Geocoding using google maps api.
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                locationName = results[1].formatted_address;
                alert(locationName);
            }
            else {
                locationName = "Unknown";
            }
        }
        else {
            locationName = "Couldn't find location. Error code: " + status;
        }
    });
    alert(locationName);
    return locationName;

}
```

I call this from a jquery event handler like this:

```
$("#id").on("event", function (event, ui) {
    $("#userLocation").text(getLocationName(latitude, longitude));
});
```

<s>Weird part is that the first alert gets the correct value of 'locationName' but the second one always returns 'undefined'. I tried initializing the variable with a value and in that case the first alert again returned the correct location name but the second one returned the initialization value. This gives me a notion that this might be a variable scope related problem but I just can't figure what.</s>

PS. I don't have any other variables (local/global) by the same name.

**Update**: The alert works fine now (thanks to Lwyrn's answer) but the return value is still wrong. I've followed the answers in the linked SO question and still I couldn't 'return' the right value. The alert did work fine.

Comment: It's not due to variable scope, it's due to asynchronous nature of the code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993563/how-do-i-return-a-variable-from-google-maps-javascript-geocoder-callback?rq=1

Comment: Then you didn't read the linked question carefully. There is **no way** to *return* a value from an asynchronous action, you need to use a callback. (OK, if you are making the AJAX call yourself you can make it synchronous instead of asynchronous, but that is just wrong for a lot of reasons.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move "alert(locationName);" into the geocoder.geocode callback. Because geocoder.geocode executes an AJAX request. When you throw the alert the var locationName is still undefined (not set).
Try it like this

```
function getLocationName(latitude, longitude, callback) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(latitude)) || isNaN(parseFloat(longitude))) {
        return false;
    }

    var locationName;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)

    // Reverse Geocoding using google maps api.
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                locationName = results[1].formatted_address;
                alert(locationName);
            }
            else {
                locationName = "Unknown";
            }
        }
        else {
            locationName = "Couldn't find location. Error code: " + status;
        }
        alert(locationName);
        callback(locationName);
    });
}
```

To get the "return" you have to create a your own callback.
Try like this

```
$("#id").on("event", function (event, ui) {
    getLocationName(latitude, longitude, function(result){
        $("#userLocation").text(result);
    });
});
```

As for the alert, the return is called before the ajax request. So you have to use a callback to be called when the ajax request has done his job!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. This sort of works. The alert 'alerts' the right value but the return doesn't return the right value to the function where I call getLocationName() from. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.

Comment: how can i assign result to a variable? i tried var x = getLocationName(latitude, longitude, function(result){
       return result;
    });

alert (x);

but this alerts undefined. any idea why?