# getting latitude longitude from address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

I am using the code below (entire html code posted) to return the latitude longitude from address but my problem is the way I am calling the function otherwise dealing with latitude longitude. The function returns null but if I display the contents inside the function (please search for "alert(results[0].geometry.location);// works fine here" I receive the right values,

what is wrong with my javascript code that the getLatLng  function returns null?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  alert (getLatLng(address));
}

var getLatLng = function(stAddress){

  return geocoder.geocode( { 'address': stAddress}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      alert(results[0].geometry.location);// works fine here
      return results[0].geometry.location;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Vancouver downtown">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return a variable from Google Maps JavaScript geocoder callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993563/how-do-i-return-a-variable-from-google-maps-javascript-geocoder-callback)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the results to the geocode, not to the outside function - getLatLng. Look up callback functions and the geocoder and it will make more sense. I had this trouble last week and I finally understood it

Comment: Could you be more specific and make some suggestions with the code please?

Comment: Geocoder is its own function, so returning a value within it does not alter any values in getLatLng. Best to look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

It really helped me

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that you are dealing with *asynchronous* code but you are expecting it to behave like *synchronous* code. Which means that `geocoder.geocode` is an asynchronous method and by invoking it your executing flow continues to next lines without waiting the results. Later on, `geocoder.geocode` will fire a callback when it is done processing your request.

Therefore, the moment you call `getLatLng` and try to see the results, it doesn't even have them yet. However, when it does - the code inside the block is ready to be executed:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': stAddress}, function(results, status) {

   // When processing done, this part is executed, yey!    

});
```

As an example, you could pass an anonymous function inside your getLatLng method and let it show the returned value when `geocoder.geocode` has finished executing.

Rather than this:

```
alert (getLatLng(address));
```

You do this:

```
getLatLng(address, function(value) {

   alert("ok: " + value);

});
```

And your method is something like this:

```
var getLatLng = function(stAddress, cb){

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': stAddress}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      return cb(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      return cb(-1);
    }
  });

}
```

See that anonymous function is named as a `cb` (shorthand to callback) inside the function.

After you run it, you should see the alert when the `geocode` method has done it's magic. Hopefully this all makes more sense now. Cheers.

Here is [**Js Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2ug9/)